# Concatenate in Query

Tags: jquery, angularjs, concatenation

I want to concatenate AngularJs variable with jquery `<% $index %>` with `onchange'=>'readURL(this)`

like

```
onchange'=>'readURL<% $index %>(this)
```

Comment: => {:onchange => "readURL("<% $index %>")"}

Comment: I want to concatenate it with readURL